# Is there a way to request authorization for both nonclinical and clinical records on iOS with HealthKit?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm looking for a way to simultaneously request authorization on iOS for both non clinical (eg. Body mass, nutrition info) and clinical info (eg. lab results, allergy) using HealthKit?
When I put an array of `HKObjectType`s as the `HKHealthStore.requestAuthorization`'s argument I can only see the form for the non clinical data.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

When your app specifies both clinical and non-clinical HealthKit types in an authorization request, a sheet for just the clinical types will appear first. Once it is dismissed, a second authorization sheet will appear for the non-clinical types.